# Pin only one post in Django-powered blog

Tags: python, django, web

I've managed to pin posts on the index page as I wanted to. Thing is, I would like to be able to pin only one post.

What I have done is create two methods, one to pin, and another to unpin, the two being BooleanFields.

What I would like to do is to, like in Twitter, when you pin one post, the other one before it loses its pinned status, and the just-pinned one takes its place.

Here is a piece of my models.py file:

```
class Post(models.Model, HitCountMixin):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='Media', default="Media/atom.png")
    text = models.TextField()
    create_date =  models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    pinned = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    hit_count_generic = GenericRelation(
        HitCount, object_id_field = 'pk',
        related_query_name = 'hit_count_generic_relation')

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def pin(self):
        self.pinned = True
        self.save()

    def unpin(self):
        self.pinned = False 
        self.save()
```

And I have this template, in which one button allows me turn the pinned Boolean Field on or off in accordance to the following if-statements:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
...
{% if post.published_date %}
    {% if post.pinned is False %}
    <div class="pin">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'pin' pk=post.pk %}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"> Pin (index)</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    {% if post.pinned is True %}
    <div class="pin">
        <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'unpin' pk=post.pk %}">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin"> Unpin (index)</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Here is a snippet from the urls.py file:

```
...

url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),

...

# pin | unpin
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/pin', views.pin_post, name='pin'),
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/unpin', views.unpin_post, name='unpin'),
...
```

And the views.py:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    paginate_by = 5 

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')

...

# pin post -> index
@login_required
def pin_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.pin()
    return redirect('index')

# unpin post <- index
@login_required
def unpin_post(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.unpin()
    return redirect('index')
```

What I would like to happend is that once I set the pinned `BooleanField` to `True`, the previous pinned `BooleanField` post is set to false. For now I have managed only to pin multiple posts at once.

Comment: What kind of help do you expect asking the question without any line of code?

Comment: alright, I'll edit and be more specific.

Comment: It is actually not so difficult. You can do it via normal get/post or using ajax. Ajax, i think, is better option. Pass id of post with ajax request and call function which will iterate over all posts and set only one post pinned.

Comment: also please include view which renders posts and probably also calls pin function

Comment: @AlexanderTyapkov how would I proceed to do this via get/post? I don't fully understand AJAX yet.

Comment: you can do it even easier, have a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pin post then you can just unpin all the rest of the posts:

```
@login_required
def pin_post(request, pk):
    for p in Post.objects.all():
        if post.pinned: post.unpin()
    post = Post.objects.filter(pk=pk).first()
    post.pin()
    return redirect('index')
```

Comment: had to do a few minor tweaks with in your code but the idea worked perfect nonetheless. Thank you very much!